# xtext validation of subobjects

Tags: validation, xtext

i have the fallowing DSL in Xtext:
I want to validate, that if ObjectB has Element, that the containing objects (ObjectA) do not have Element. I get the Warning to ObjectB but not to Object A.

```
Domainmodel:
    ObjectA | ObjectB
    ;

ObjectB:
    'ObjectB'
    '{'
    (element = Element)?
    (objects += ObjectA)*
    '}'
;

ObjectA:
'ObjectA'
  '{'
  (element = Element)?
  '}'

;

 Element:
    'Element' name=ID
 ;
```

I would like a warning like the fallowing also in ObjectA:

```
@check
def ObjectinObject(ObjectB object)
{
  if(object.element != null)
  {
     for (ObjectA e : object.objects)
     {
         if(e.element != null)
              {//The fallowing Code will make Warning at the element and the subelement
              warning('warning', DomainmodelPackage$Literals::DOMAINMODEL__ELEMENT)
              warning('warning2',e.element ,DomainmodelPackage$Literals::ELEMENT__NAME)
              }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several "groups" for `warning`, `error` and `info`. One group does have `EObject` in the parameter list, the other groups not not.

You already use the one which does *not*. In that case the message is attached to the `EObject` which is the parameter of the check method.

So in order to attach a message to *any* random `EObject` you have to use a method with an `EObject` parameter. In your case:

```
protected void warning(String message, EObject source, EStructuralFeature feature);
```

and in action:

```
warning('warning', e, DomainmodelPackage$Literals::OBJECT_A__OBJECTS)
```

This second group of message methods is only available since Xtext 2.4. If you happen to use an older version, you can try this stanza (in Java, please adopt to Xtend syntax on your own):

```
getMessageAcceptor().acceptWarning('warning', e,
    DomainmodelPackage$Literals::OBJECT_A__OBJECTS, -1, 
    null);
```

Comment: thanks that helped me a lot. I tried a bit and got it to work. I didnt have OBJECT_A__OBJECTS as literals, just Object_B__OBJECTS, but that didn't work either. it was actually: warning('warning2',e.element , DomainmodelPackage$Literals::ELEMENT__NAME)